# Найти минимум в каждой строке двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, min

Как найти минимум в каждой строке двумерного массива?

```
import numpy as np

# Ввод и вывод матрицы
y = int(input('Количество элементов строки: '))
x = int(input('Количество строк: '))
matrix = np.array([[y for y in input('Значения матрицы построчно: ').split()] 
                   for x in range(x)], dtype=int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

пример исходной матрицы:

```
In [41]: matrix = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(4, 3)

In [42]: matrix
Out[42]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

минимумы по столбцам:

```
In [43]: matrix.min(axis=0)
Out[43]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

минимумы по строкам:

```
In [44]: matrix.min(axis=1)
Out[44]: array([ 1,  4,  7, 10])
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> при матрице [[0, 2, 9], [6, 4, 8], [7, 3, 1]] находится min не в
>   каждой строке, т.е. для строк выводит [0 2 1]

все правильно работает:

```
In [45]: a = np.array([[0, 2, 9], [6, 4, 8], [7, 3, 1]])

In [46]: a
Out[46]:
array([[0, 2, 9],
       [6, 4, 8],
       [7, 3, 1]])

In [47]: a.min(axis=1)
Out[47]: array([0, 4, 1])
```

Comment: при матрице [[0, 2, 9], [6, 4, 8], [7, 3, 1]] находится min не в каждой строке, т.е. для строк выводит [0 2 1]

Comment: @strquest, см. UPDATE. Поверьте такой жирный bug не прошел бы тесты и не смог бы попасть в релиз Numpy. Подозреваю что ошибка у вас.

Comment: да, извините, у меня косяк был

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
minimums = [min(el) for el in matrix]
```